# XML syntax highlighting

Tags: listings, xml

I use the following code to include some XML code:

```
\lstset{language=XML}
\begin{lstlisting}
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified"
   xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="points">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="point">
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="x" type="xs:unsignedShort" use="required" />
            <xs:attribute name="y" type="xs:unsignedShort" use="required" />
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
\end{lstlisting}
```

But only `?xml version` is highlighted. Is there any other predefined XML syntax highlighting?

Comment: [minted](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/minted/) might have better support?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

XML language has very limited support for keywords. You can define more keywords yourself:

```
\lstset{
  language=XML,
  morekeywords={encoding,
    xs:schema,xs:element,xs:complexType,xs:sequence,xs:attribute}
}
```

Answer (score 70):

You can define your own language. The best I could get so far:

```
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.6}
\definecolor{cyan}{rgb}{0.0,0.6,0.6}

\lstset{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  columns=fullflexible,
  showstringspaces=false,
  commentstyle=\color{gray}\upshape
}

\lstdefinelanguage{XML}
{
  morestring=[b]",
  morestring=[s]{>}{<},
  morecomment=[s]{<?}{?>},
  stringstyle=\color{black},
  identifierstyle=\color{darkblue},
  keywordstyle=\color{cyan},
  morekeywords={xmlns,version,type}% list your attributes here
}
```

Here is an example of highlighted XML with the settings above:

[image: XML syntax highlighting]

I'd like to set the syntax bits such as `<`, `>`, `</`, `=`, `:` in gray as well, because they don't hold relevant information, but this would brake other parts of the highlighting. Maybe someone else can improve it and send a fix to the maintainer of listings package.

Comment: I want the comments in the XML which are inside <!-- --> in gray same as <? ?>. Can you tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 25):

Here's another style which is rather hacky and stingy about additional whitespace because of the attribute delimiter that starts with a space:

```
\definecolor{maroon}{rgb}{0.5,0,0}
\definecolor{darkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\lstdefinelanguage{XML}
{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  morestring=[s]{"}{"},
  morecomment=[s]{?}{?},
  morecomment=[s]{!--}{--},
  commentstyle=\color{darkgreen},
  moredelim=[s][\color{black}]{>}{<},
  moredelim=[s][\color{red}]{\ }{=},
  stringstyle=\color{blue},
  identifierstyle=\color{maroon}
}
```

Example output:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Finally, a style that really produces good XML formatting (for the documents I tested at least). I modified it a bit to get (almost) the same formatting as Firefox when it displays an XML file. `\lstdefinelanguage{XML}{
  columns=fullflexible,
  basicstyle=\rmfamily,
  commentstyle=\ttfamily\itshape\color{green!50!black},
  morestring=[s]{"}{"},
  morecomment=[s]{?}{?},
  morecomment=[s]{!--}{--},
  morecomment=[s]{!DOCTYPE}{]},
  moredelim=[s][\color{black}]{>}{<},
  moredelim=[s][\bfseries\color{black}]{\ }{=},
  stringstyle=\color{blue},
  identifierstyle=\bfseries\color{violet}
}
`

Comment: How can this work if you have `<!DOCTYPE html>` on the first line?

Comment: @kojow7 That is not XML, you would need to introduce additional delimiter rules.

Answer (score 20):

A synthesis of the previous answers that works best for me, especially w.r.t. highlighting the angle brackets. Using SVG Color names (`svgnames`):

```
\lstdefinelanguage{XML}
{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
  morestring=[b]",
  moredelim=[s][\bfseries\color{Maroon}]{<}{\ },
  moredelim=[s][\bfseries\color{Maroon}]{</}{>},
  moredelim=[l][\bfseries\color{Maroon}]{/>},
  moredelim=[l][\bfseries\color{Maroon}]{>},
  morecomment=[s]{<?}{?>},
  morecomment=[s]{<!--}{-->},
  commentstyle=\color{DarkOliveGreen},
  stringstyle=\color{blue},
  identifierstyle=\color{red}
}
```

The order of the `\more...` commands seems to be important. Note that you need a font that supports bold-face to be [Using \ttfamily with \bfseries (or how to enable bold in fixed-width font)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33039/8057). 
[Code](https://github.com/krlmlr/lm-template/tree/xml) is at GitHub.

[image: Example output]

Comment: You forget the comments: `morecomment=[s]{<!--}{-->},`.

Comment: one improvement: adding `alsoletter=-:` will allow the semicolon in attribute names (such as `xmlns:xs`) to be coloured and similarly for attribute names with a dash, e.g. `list-type`.
`

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for a solution that will apply color on `<`, `</`, `>` and `/>`. I discovered that applying `basicstyle` in the `lstdefinelanguage` has solved my problem.

With the `basicstyle`, I defined the style that is applied for all the code content without regards of the content type (`identifiers`, `keywords`, ...) and then, the other style will be applied. (added `basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{darkblue}\bfseries`)

```
\lstdefinelanguage{XML}
{
  basicstyle=\ttfamily\color{darkblue}\bfseries,
  morestring=[b]",
  morestring=[s]{>}{<},
  morecomment=[s]{<?}{?>},
  stringstyle=\color{black},
  identifierstyle=\color{darkblue},
  keywordstyle=\color{cyan},
  morekeywords={xmlns,version,type}% list your attributes here
}
```

Comment: I cannot see how this colorizes the missing characters. At least it did not work for me. Could you please double check if you missed something and add a screenshot please?

Comment: I needed to change `darkblue` to `DarkBlue` when using svgnames