# XML highlighting - different style for attributes

Tags: listings, highlighting, xml

I need to highlight syntax in my LaTeX presentation, so I've found this answer:
[XML syntax highlighting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10255/xml-syntax-highlighting/11134#11134)

```
\lstdefinelanguage{XML}
{
  morestring=[b]",
  morestring=[s]{>}{<},
  morecomment=[s]{<?}{?>},
  stringstyle=\color{black},
  identifierstyle=\color{darkblue},
  keywordstyle=\color{cyan},
  morekeywords={xmlns,version,type},
  backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily\color{gray},
  numbersep=0.5pt
}
```

Unfortunately I didn't find any way, how to specify extra style for text in attributes.

For example:

```
<xml>
    <person age="22" sex="female">Ann</person>
</xml>
```

It the case above, `Ann` and `22`, `female` would have the same style... How to separate styles for those two things?

Comment: Has there been any development on this yet? Does the answer provided help any or not?

Comment: @Edd I'm sorry, i've already ran the presentation without using your advice, anyway, i'll take a look at it soon and if it help, i swear, i'll give you an upvote/accept-question-mark. I'm busy right now, just give me few more days...

Comment: Absolutely no problem. I was just curious as to whether this fixed your problem or whether there was something deeper to investigate. I'm not so fussed about the upvote/answer to be honest!

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 10):

When you add the color package and change

```
morestring=[b]",
```

into

```
morestring=[b][\color{red}]",
```

the attributes will color red.

This will color the attributes red in your xml listings.

```
\begin{lstlisting}[language=xml, frame=single]
<xml>
    <person age="22" sex="female">Ann</person>
</xml>
\end{lstlisting}
```

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{lightgray}{rgb}{.7,.7,.7}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{.4,.4,.4}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0,0,.3}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=xml, frame=single]
<xml>
    <person age="22" sex="female">Ann</person>
</xml>
\end{lstlisting}

 \lstdefinelanguage{XML}
{
  morestring=[b][\color{red}]",
  morestring=[s]{>}{<},
  morecomment=[s]{<?}{?>},
  stringstyle=\color{black},
  identifierstyle=\color{darkblue},
  keywordstyle=\color{cyan},
  morekeywords={xmlns,version,type},
  backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily\color{gray},
  numbersep=0.5pt
}

\begin{lstlisting}[language=xml, frame=single]
<xml>
    <person age="22" sex="female">Ann</person>
</xml>
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}




 \lstdefinelanguage{XML}
{
  morestring=[b][\color{red}]",
  morestring=[s]{>}{<},
  morecomment=[s]{<?}{?>},
  stringstyle=\color{black},
  identifierstyle=\color{darkblue},
  keywordstyle=\color{cyan},
  morekeywords={xmlns,version,type},
  backgroundcolor=\color{lightgray},
  numbers=left,
  numberstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily\color{gray},
  numbersep=0.5pt
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The [minted package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/minted/) produces code which has tag-names, attribute-names, attribute-values and tag-contents printed differently, so the following code would produce the output which follows it:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\begin{minted}{xml}
    <xml>
        <person age="22" sex="female">Ann</person>
    </xml>
\end{minted}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of sample minted XML output]

Note, however, that the minted package use a python program called pygments, which is fairly straightforward to install as detailed in the [minted documentation](http://ctan.sqsol.co.uk/macros/latex/contrib/minted/minted.pdf).