# Add html preformatted text into latex

Tags: listings

I am writing my thesis using LaTeX, and a would like to add some code in it. I tried so far the `listings` by I am not satisfied with the result. Is there a way to add a pre-formated code in HTML into LaTeX?

I want to take my code from `Kate` as a pre-formated text in HTML and put it into my thesis text. Is that possible?

For example I have the following code in C:

```
struct cpu_info {
    long unsigned utime, ntime, stime, itime;
    long unsigned iowtime, irqtime, sirqtime;
};
```

I copy from Kate that code as HTML. The contents of the clipboard are

```
<pre style='color:#141312;background-color:#ffffff;'>
<b>struct</b> cpu_info {
    <span style='color:#0057ae;'>long</span> <span style='color:#0057ae;'>unsigned</span> utime, ntime, stime, itime;
    <span style='color:#0057ae;'>long</span> <span style='color:#0057ae;'>unsigned</span> iowtime, irqtime, sirqtime;
};</pre>
```

I want to insert this code in Latex in order to produce the formatted text of the above HTML code without using listings if it is possible.

My code is written in C so if anyone has a good `lstset` for C, that would be also great for me.

I use `\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}`.

Comment: maybe try the `verbatim` environment...

Comment: In which way does the output produced by listing not satisfy you?

Comment: In order to achieve the same result with an editor formatting, it could take me hours to do, as it is the first time that I am using latex. I managed to make an lstset put its output is very poor. So I asked if there is out there any "quick" solution.

Comment: XML/HTML isn't that well supported by `listings`. See [XML syntax highlighting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10255/xml-syntax-highlighting), which might be a duplicate. There is also the [`minted`](http://code.google.com/p/minted/) package which uses [Pygments](http://pygments.org/), a Python syntax highlighter, which might have better XML support.

Comment: Also, because your question got migrated from stackoverflow.com to us, please make sure you have a registered account on both sites so that they can be associated to each other. This is required so that you gain ownership of this question on this site.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

It is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Comment: Ok, hello from here and thanks for the replies. @MartinScharrer i edited my question to be more specific. I do not try to highlight html code, I try to import html code as highlighting. Sorry if that was not clear from the beginning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If possible, I would just use the `C` code directly. Here is an example:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstset{
    language=C,
    basicstyle=\small\sffamily,
    frame=tblr,
    backgroundcolor=\color{yellow!20},
    numbers=left,
    xleftmargin=5.0ex,
    numberstyle=\tiny,
    numbersep=4pt,
    stepnumber=2,
    %showstringspaces=false,
    keywordstyle=\color{blue}\bfseries
    }

\lstset{emph={%  Adjust any special keywords
    printf%
    },emphstyle={\color{red}\bfseries}%
}%

\begin{lstlisting}
/* Hello World program */

#include<stdio.h>

struct cpu_info {
    long unsigned utime, ntime, stime, itime;
    long unsigned iowtime, irqtime, sirqtime;
};

main()
{
    printf("Hello World");
}\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Closer to the original Kate formatting (but I'm not sure why it leaves 'struct' uncolored, but colors 'unsigned' and 'long', since they're all keywords):

`\definecolor{keyword}{HTML}{0057AE}
\definecolor{basic}{HTML}{141312}
\definecolor{background}{HTML}{FFFFFF}

\lstset{language=C,
  backgroundcolor=\color{background},
  basicstyle=\color{basic}\ttfamily,
  keywordstyle=\color{keyword}\bfseries,
}`

Comment: I wasn't mimicking any formatting, just suggesting that it is better to simply use the C code directly rather than try to format the HTML version of the C code.

Comment: @pe I ended with your suggestion using C code directly. There was a problem with the code that overfilled the margins of my text, due to many nested code. The solution to that was to minimize the size of tabs. With a little search I found the `tabsize` parameter, set it to 2 and "Wohoooo" problem is gone. Thanks all for your help.

Comment: @PeterGrill sure, I just added it in case the original poster got picky about specific colors matching what Kate produced. No doubt it's better to just use listings for C in any case.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of inserting preformatted html :(

Comment: @Ell: Yeah, I suggested using the C code directly as the op stated "My code is written in C so if anyone has a good `lstset` for C, that would be also great for me."

Comment: I suppose. Maybe this question is a duplicate though. Oh well, I've found a way around my issue anyway.

Comment: @Ell: If you found what you wanted in another answer here, you should add a link to it in a comment so that others may find it. If you came up with the solution it would be helpful if you posted it as an answer here.