# How to highlight the XML code in latex overleaf

Tags: listings, highlighting, xml

I followed few answers mentioned here to highlight the XML content in my latex and tried to combine best things together from different answers but for some reason nothing is being highlighted in my XML? Can someone please help me how to make XML content in my latex to look appealing? I tried the following answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/11134/226278

My XML is quite large and spans over 2-3 pages but now it's being displayed in a frame with line number so looks nice but none of the tags or strings is being highlighted except for some strings in the XML header. I would like to highlight the tags and strings in them so it would look nicer.

```
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.4,0.4,0.4}
\definecolor{darkblue}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,0.6}
\definecolor{cyan}{rgb}{0.0,0.6,0.6}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}
\geometry{a4paper}

 \lstset{
        language=xml,
        tabsize=3,
        %frame=lines,
        caption=Bulk test data events for rail sector
        label=code:rail1,
        frame=shadowbox,
        xleftmargin=20pt,
        framexleftmargin=15pt,
        numbers=left,
        numberstyle=\tiny,
        numbersep=5pt,
        breaklines=true,
        showstringspaces=false,
        basicstyle=\footnotesize,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        columns=fullflexible,
        showstringspaces=false,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
        morestring=[b]",
        moredelim=[s][\bfseries\color{Maroon}]{<}{\ },
        moredelim=[s][\bfseries\color{Maroon}]{</}{>},
        moredelim=[l][\bfseries\color{Maroon}]{/>},
        moredelim=[l][\bfseries\color{Maroon}]{>},
        morecomment=[s]{<?}{?>},
        morecomment=[s]{<!--}{-->},
        commentstyle=\color{DarkOliveGreen},
        stringstyle=\color{blue},
        identifierstyle=\color{red},
    }
    \lstinputlisting{pics/RailSector.xml}
```

For example this is my sample XML file which I want to highlight and present in the pics folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<hello:mydocument>
  <manufacturing>court</manufacturing>
  <bend>grabbed</bend>
  <quick>613049078</quick>
  <am>
    <brief>-2019050644</brief>
    <judge>955087623.417459</judge>
    <birds>green</birds>
    <join>among</join>
    <slight>
      <box>loose</box>
      <butter>table</butter>
      <afternoon>good</afternoon>
      <suddenly>rear</suddenly>
      <kitchen>copper</kitchen>
      <locate>802538930</locate>
    </slight>
    <wagon>1157100273.040341</wagon>
  </am>
  <this>1903268890</this>
  <rule>-1380139207</rule>
</hello:mydocument>
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.  We can't do much without `pics/RailSector.xml`.  Could you adjust your example to use the `lstlisting` environment?  I assume that it would have the same highlighting issue that you're trying to solve.

Comment: @Teepeemm Thanks for the response. I have added a sample XML file content in the above code. What is the difference between `lstset` and `lstlisting`? is it possible to do the highlighting in the above code itself?

Comment: Just a silly question: is that your whole document? Do you have a `\begin{document}` and an `\end{document}` ?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After correcting two things in your MWE (adding `\documentclass{article}`, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`) It seemed like nothing was being highlighted besides the first line of your text.

This is because everything was defined in one color (Maroon) while the comments (defined by `<? ?>`) were different.

changing the Maroon color did not make **everything** highlighted. For that you need to tell listings to look in the text by adding `*` in the `lstset`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

 \lstset{
        language=xml,
        tabsize=3,
        %frame=lines,
        caption=Bulk test data events for rail sector
        label=code:rail1,
        frame=shadowbox,
        xleftmargin=20pt,
        framexleftmargin=15pt,
        numbers=left,
        numberstyle=\tiny,
        numbersep=5pt,
        breaklines=true,
        showstringspaces=false,
        basicstyle=\footnotesize,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        columns=fullflexible,
        showstringspaces=false,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
        morestring=[b]",
        moredelim=*[s][\bfseries\color{Maroon}]{<}{\ },
        moredelim=*[s][\bfseries\color{blue}]{</}{>},
        moredelim=*[l][\bfseries\color{red}]{/>},
        moredelim=*[l][\bfseries\color{Maroon}]{>},
        morecomment=[s]{<?}{?>},
        morecomment=[s]{<!--}{-->},
        commentstyle=\color{DarkOliveGreen},
        stringstyle=\color{blue},
        identifierstyle=\color{red},
    }
    
\begin{document}
    \lstinputlisting{RailSector.xml}
\end{document}
```

As for the question in the comments. `\lstset` is the settings definition. You tell the package what language you're using and what the keywords highlights are.

You then can type the code using `lstlisting` environment or input it from file (as you did) using `\lstinputlisting`

Using `lstlisting` is considered better practice **WHEN ASKING A QUESTION HERE** because it allows us to see the entire code without jumping between files. Here's an example of a MWE with the code in `lstlisting`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

 \lstset{
        language=xml,
        tabsize=3,
        morestring=[b]",
        moredelim=*[s][\bfseries\color{Maroon}]{<}{\ },
        moredelim=*[s][\bfseries\color{blue}]{</}{>},
        moredelim=*[l][\bfseries\color{red}]{/>},
        moredelim=*[l][\bfseries\color{Maroon}]{>},
        morecomment=[s]{<?}{?>},
        morecomment=[s]{<!--}{-->},
        commentstyle=\color{DarkOliveGreen},
        stringstyle=\color{blue},
        identifierstyle=\color{red},
    }
    
\begin{document}
    \begin{lstlisting}
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<hello:mydocument>
  <manufacturing>court</manufacturing>
  <bend>grabbed</bend>
  <quick>613049078</quick>
  <this>1903268890</this>
  <rule>-1380139207</rule>
</hello:mydocument>
    \end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot :)