# Listings XML highlighting problems - values between tags

Tags: listings, syntax-highlighting

I'm using a custom style to get syntax highlighting for XML in `Listings` from [this thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10255/xml-syntax-highlighting/140242) but I'm having issues in regards to values between tags getting wrongly targeted.

The styling I have is

```
\lstdefinelanguage{XML}
{
   basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
   morestring=[b]", 
   moredelim=[s][\color{darkblue}]{<}{\ },
   moredelim=[s][\color{darkblue}]{</}{>},
   moredelim=[l][\color{darkblue}]{/>},
   moredelim=[l][\color{darkblue}]{>},
   morecomment=[s]{<?}{?>},
   morecomment=[s]{<!--}{-->},
   commentstyle=\color{darkgreen},
   stringstyle=\color{darkgreen},
   identifierstyle=\color{darkred}
}
```

and it causes different parts of the value between tags, i.e. "Author name goes here" in

```
<Author>Author name goes here</Author>
```

to get styled differently. The first set of characters up to the first space gets the same colour as the tag whereas the rest gets the identifierstyle colour.

I have managed to narrow it down to the line

```
moredelim=[s][\color{darkblue}]{<}{\ },
```

incorrectly targeting the first word in the value but I have not been able to find any fixes for it.

Any solutions that either make the value between the tags become fully in the identifierstlye or one that specifically targets the value between tags (as I preferrably want to have it be another colour) would be largely appreciated.

[image: Image showing the incorrect colour styling]

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.