How to highlight XML code with piton package?
How to highlight XML code with piton package?
MWE:
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{piton}
\NewPitonLanguage{XML}%
% https://github.com/JakeKazu/tex_set/blob/master/texmf/tex/lstlang1.sty
{morekeywords={version, encoding, standalone},%
sensitive,%
morestring=[s]{"}{"},%
morecomment=[s]{?}{?},%
morecomment=[s]{<!--}{-->},%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{Piton}[language=XML, line-numbers, auto-gobble]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- employee information -->
<employee>
  <fio>
    <first_name>Smith</first_name>
    <last_name>Will</last_name>
    <second_name>Willard</second_name>
  </fio>
  <post>actor</post>
  <work_address>
    <postal-code>000000</postal-code>
    <city>Philadelphia</city>
    <street>street</street>
    <house_number>1</house_number>
    <email>post@xxxx.com</email>
    <telephone code="8-XXXX">XX-XX-XX</telephone>
  </work_address>
</employee>
\end{Piton}
\end{document}

My result:

I want it to look like this:

enter link description here

Your example misses \usepackage{xcolor} (as stated by the error it produces), did you just forget to include it in the example?

Everything works. Use LuaLaTeX as a compiler. @Torbjørn T.

Now I'm confused, are you saying adding xcolor solved your problem? If not, what exactly are you asking?

Everything works without the xcolor package. See the photo, @Torbjørn T.

OK, it didn't for me, but fine. What is your question then? What do you want to do?

Sorry, your question is unclear. What do you want the output to look like? If I use your code and additionally load the xcolor package, it will output exactly what you show. So, if this is not the output your are looking for, please explain your aim in more detail (and please do this by editing your question). You might want to look at the manual of the piton package.

Maybe you could highlight XML code with piton if you define your own language and styles. Some ideas from https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10255/xml-syntax-highlighting could be useful (that question is about listings, which has a similar syntax to define new languages -- but a crude try has not been successful). For XML, minted is a much better choice, since it has a complete parser for the languages it supports.

I've read the documentation, but I can't create my own language for coloring XML code. @Jasper Habicht

Here is what you can do with piton:
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{piton}

\NewPitonLanguage{XML}
  { 
    morekeywords = { version , encoding , standalone , xmlns , type , version } ,
    alsoother=$,
    alsoletter=:,
    tag=<>,
    morestring=[d]",
  }

\SetPitonStyle[XML]
  {
    Tag = \color{blue} ,
    String = \color{black} , 
    Keyword = \color{cyan}
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{Piton}[language=XML, line-numbers, auto-gobble]
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mods xmlns="http://www.loc.gov/modes/v3" version="3.4">
  <titleInfo>
    <nonSort>The </nonSort>
    <title>C programming language</title>
  </titleInfo>
  <name type="personal">
    <namePart>Kernighan, Brian W..</namePart>
  </name>
  <name type="personal">
    <namePart>Ritchie, Dennis M.</namePart>
  </name>
  <originInfo>
    <place>
      <placeTerm type="text">Englewood Cliffs, NJ</placeTerm>
    </place>
    <publisher>Prentice-Hall</publisher>
    <dateIssued>1978</dateIssued>
  </originInfo>
</mods>
\end{Piton}
\end{document}

That file must be compiled with LuaLaTeX.

